# Split git-status porcelain output by index and worktree

Tags: git

I want to run `git-status` and only show changes in the index or worktree respectively. While the human readable output somewhat separates those lines, the porcelain invocation does not.

```
git status --porcelain=v2

1 MM N... 100644 100644 100644 4aa81... e00fe... A.cpp
1 .M N... 100644 100644 100644 ceaa5... ceaa5... B.cpp
```

So when I have a file that would be modified in both, the index and the worktree, the output should be 2 separate lines for those files (`A.cpp`), one for the worktree modification and one for the index.

Is this possible without manually picking them apart later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status --porcelain | grep "^\w."` for index.

`git status --porcelain | grep "^.\w"` for working tree.

Comment: Unfortunately the command is run without a SHELL environment